# direct boost::asio::buffer read and write

Tags: c++, boost, buffer, boost-asio

He110.

How can I directly read from or write into an asio mutable_buffer(_1) or const_buffer(_1)?

I have a function which receives the same parameters as boost::asio::read/write. In some cases it passes the call to boost::asio::read/write and in other cases it does the task itself by writing/reading to/from the buffer.

Another question, I want to overload this function with one that accepts an asio::streambuf. Is there a simpler way so I can avoid duplicate code as well?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6560208/boost-asio-async-read-async-write-wrapper) did not answer all my questions!